# Looking for a lightweight java-compatible in-memory key-value store

Tags: java, nosql, berkeley-db, key-value-store

Berkeley DB would be the best choice probably but I can't use it due to licensing issues.

Are there any alternatives?

Comment: @Stephen C: you are welcome to edit and provide better explanation. About "responding sarcastically": it sounds strange for me that alternative to Berkeley DB is HashMap.

Comment: upvoting - question seems legit, and not that much sarcasm going around. Given, question could have stated from the start that hashmaps would not cut it.

Comment: OK @Roman ... what **DO** you mean by "//sarcasam" in your comment below??

Comment: Why not check nosql-database.org --> Key Value / Store section and have an answer for yourself. Using IMDG , also a [Key Value Store](http://blogs.alachisoft.com/tayzgrid/using-an-in-memory-key-value-store-to-scale-java-apps/) ,gives you the option to scale

Answer (score 8):

You can try [Hazelcast](http://www.hazelcast.com). Just add hazelcast.jar to your classpath. And start coding

```
java.util.Map map = Hazelcast.getMap("myMap");
```

You'll get an in-memory, distributed, dynamically scalable data grid which performs super fast.

Answer (score 3):

Your question could mean one of two things.

If you mean a data structure for storing key-value pairs, use one of the [`Map`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) instances that are a standard part of the JDK.

If however you are after an in-memory key-value store then I would suggest taking a look at [EHCache](http://ehcache.org/) or even [memcached](http://memcached.org/).

Comment: @cletus : doesn't hashmap use in-memory key-value store?

Answer (score 3):

[Chronicle-Map](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map) is a strong alternative.

- Pure Java, simply `java.util.Map` implementation
- Stores the data off-heap, optionally persisted to disk via memory-mapped files
- Open source, permissive Apache 2.0 license
- Incredibly fast, can manage millions of updates/queries per second ([see exact numbers](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map/blob/master/README.md#concurrenthashmap-v-chroniclemap))

Answer (score 2):

[HashMap](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)?

Comment: It lacks transactions management and possibility to keep some data in the disk and another part in-memory and so on.. //sarcasm

Comment: Ah, I see :) There was a problem a while back with someone wanting to develop stuff for Android but needed to use a storage-backed hashmap because the size of his data was too large. Something similar, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is  a two-year old post but I've been messing around with [Infinispan](http://www.jboss.org/infinispan.html) recently and I like it so far.  I'm not an expert by any means but it was not too difficult for me to set up a distributed cache with a few nodes and I was pulling some data from them in about an hour.

Answer (score 2):

[MapDb](http://www.mapdb.org) is an alternative to Berkley with a friendly Apache 2 license.

- Provides key-value store via java's Map interface
- Lightweight (300KB jar)
- Fast and threadsafe
- Persists changes to disk if you want to
- Many other [features](http://www.mapdb.org/features.html)

Comment: Lightweight? mvn copy-dependencies collects some 14 MB for mapdb:3.0.5

Answer (score 1):

[jdbm](http://jdbm.sourceforge.net/) works great for this sort of thing.  It's intended for storing on disk in a paged file, provides for basic transaction support (no guarantees on isolation, but ACD are covered).  We've used it in a production system with fairly wide deployment and have been quite pleased with the performance, stability, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [jredis](http://code.google.com/p/jredis/). It's a Java client for Redis, a persistent key-value store. There's also a JDBC driver for it: code.google.com/p/jdbc-redis/.

Answer (score 0):

There are lightweigh or embedded dbs like HSQLDB, Derby, SQLite
But like others don't understand why you need a db to store key/values...

Why not a Map? 
Need to keep key/values on app reboot?

Also it's perhaps not what you need but with html5 on up to date browsers you have localStorage that permits you to store key/values in the browser using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to try a [Redisson](https://redisson.org). You will able to use distributed and scalable `Map` or `ConcurrentMap` and other (Set, List, Queue, Lock ...) implementations on top of high performance key-value [Redis](http://redis.io/) server.

Easy example:

```
Redisson redisson = Redisson.create();

ConcurrentMap<String, SomeObject> map = redisson.getMap("anyMap");

...

redisson.shutdown();
```